# Trying to message a button from another class

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, oop

I'm new to Objective-C so I may be doing this completely wrong, and if I am please correct me. I am trying to make a separate class in my iPhone app just for skinning buttons. My hope is that this will allow me to reuse as much code as possible but before I spend too much time on it, I would like to know if its possible/a good idea to send a message to a UI Control from another class, and if i can, how should I do it? right now im trying to pass the sender ID to my SkinTools class and message that but it doesn't look like it will allow me to message the layer object.

So, am I just completely off the wall here, or is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out categories was the answer I needed, then I can just add a skin method to each control I use. I can even put them all in the same file to make it easy to get to.

Answer (score 2):

Consider looking into using the [delegate pattern](http://mohrt.blogspot.com/2010/01/cocoa-and-delegates.html).

Comment: I read that article, and it really helped me understand delegates, but I don't understand how that will allow me to call my button skinning method. I want to be able to put in my viewDidLoad method something like `code`[skinner skinButton:button];`code` to fire off my skinning method, but I cannot seem to find a way to send messages to layer from my skinner class. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

One could just use the *addTarget:selector:* method for this purpose. As target set the class you want to send the message to, as selector the method you want to call on the class.

You could add some iVars to your class, like *id buttonTarget* and *SEL buttonSelector* and create an initializer like *-initButtonWithTarget:selector:* to set these values on initialization.